# Access a control in Codebehind that's in a Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, webforms, code-behind

In my ASP.NET WebForms application using Scafolding I have many pages where I need to restrict certain links based on user's role. 
For instance, in my Site.Master in my `<LoggedTemplate>` along with other `<li>`, I have a `<li>` for Admin page also. By default, that is not visible, but if the user is logged as an Admin, then I want it to make visible. Which I am not able to do. Here's the code for it :

```
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" id="adminLink" visible="false" href="~/Admin/Admin_Page">Admin</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Inquiries/Default.aspx">Inquiry</a></li>
```

In my Codebehind, in `Page_Load` I am not able to access `adminLink` only.

Simialrly, in one of the `Default` page of a `Model`, the list has links to View, Insert & Delete. If the user is admin, then only I want to show Insert & Delete links. Here's the code for it :

```
       <td>
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# FriendlyUrl.Href("~/Channels/Details", Item.ChannelId) %>' Text="View" /> |

            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="editLink" NavigateUrl='<%# FriendlyUrl.Href("~/Channels/Edit", Item.ChannelId) %>' Text="Edit" /> | 
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# FriendlyUrl.Href("~/Channels/Delete", Item.ChannelId) %>' Text="Delete" />

        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I tried adding

```
<% if (CommonUtilities.IsUserAdmin) { %>
hyperlinks for Insert & delete & finally 
<% } %>
```

but this was giving error. I added `ID` to `editLink`, but again cannot access it in `Page_Load` method.

I am sure, their must be some method to work out with this which I am not able to find yet. 
How to deal with this problem ?? Please help me, I have several pages & links to hide & show based on admin role.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks WEDEBE for pointing out to mix `<a>` and .
That point gave me a way out. In my design, I change `<a>` to `<asp:HyperLink>` & removed code from Codebehind. In design only I tried checking hte role of user & then adding full `<li>`. Like this :

```
   <LoggedInTemplate>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <% if (VincitoreCRMApplication.CommonUtilities.IsCurrentUserAdmin)
            { %>
             <li> <asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="adminLink" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Admin_Page.aspx">Admin</asp:HyperLink>  </li>
           <% } %>
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Inquiries/Default.aspx">Inquiry</a></li>
```

With the other 2 HyperLink's also I did the same way :

```
    <% if (VincitoreCRMApplication.CommonUtilities.IsCurrentUserAdmin)
   { %>

        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="editLink" NavigateUrl='<%# FriendlyUrl.Href("~/Channels/Edit", Item.ChannelId) %>' Text="Edit" /> | 
         <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# FriendlyUrl.Href("~/Channels/Delete", Item.ChannelId) %>' Text="Delete" />
    <% } %>
```

And this worked. But I realized one thing, when If I add

```
  <% if (VincitoreCRMApplication.CommonUtilities.IsCurrentUserAdmin) { %>
```

like this, in a single line, it's not working. But on adding the curly braces in new line, it works. I know this sounds very strange, I also can't make out why it happens so. But it is fact, that what I have faced & learned.

I know this is quiet simple thing, but just in case my code helps anyone, have shared here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `FindControl`. For example:

```
Label adminLabel = LoggedInTemplate.FindControl("adminLink") as Label;
adminLabel.visible = true;
```

Works for me in a few templates, dont know about LoggedInTemplate tho, but can't see why not.

edit: didn't realize ur using `<a>`. Not sure why you mix asp hyperlink and html but anyway, logic is still the same.

Comment: LoggedInTemplate is not accessible in Site.Master.cs, nor it has any id attribute.  Changed the <a> in <li> to <asp:HyperLink>.   (LoginView) logView.LoggedInTemplate has no find or so methods. So, I tried logView.find("adminLink"), but it returned null. LoggedInTemplate is also a subclass of ITemplate.

Comment: Thanks WEDWBE, though the codebehind didn't worked. On changing <a> to <asp:Hyperlink> and adding the code as shown in my answer, things worked. But even replacing <a>, the <li> and <ul> is html only. What are the replacements for that for creating navigation bar on top ? Any idea !!!